# Rajawali transparent background of "RajawaliTextureView" (Augmented Reality)

Tags: android, opengl-es, augmented-reality, rajawali, android-camera2

I want to display a "[RajawaliTextureView](https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/blob/master/rajawali/src/main/java/org/rajawali3d/surface/RajawaliTextureView.java)" over a Camera2 API preview (also TextureView), but the the background isn't transparent.
The result is a black background and I can't see the camera preview.

How can I make a transparent background of the **RajawaliTextureView**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with a TextureView. Even if you render a transparent clear color, it will be against a white background because of how Android uses texture views in its drawing system.

Please read https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/wiki/Using-RajawaliSurfaceView-and-RajawaliTextureView#which-one-to-use